# Facebook example not working (Dll not loaded)

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I cannot seem to get the facebook example code to work at all. I've created a blank unity project, imported the latest version of the facebook sdk (5.1 at time of writing) and entered my AppId in facebook settings.

When I start the interactiveconsole example and click FB.Init I see the 'loading dll' line in the unity console and if I fire up fiddler, I see the DLL come back as a 200.

Unfortunately the unity app just says DLL: not loaded and I get no more feedback.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

NOTES :

1) Just tried this under MacOSX instead of Windows 8.1 and it worked fine... Just not working in windows, which doesn't help me as my Api is a windows IIS hosted project, so I need to get this working under Windows.

2) Just tried on a completely different machine (still Windows 8.1) and it also worked fine, so the issue must be environmental.

3) Completely removed facebook SDK from my unity project and re-added from the asset store. This verison is older (5.03 rather than 5.1) and it seems to work ok. Possibly an issue with Unity + Windows 8.1 + Facebook SDK 5.1.